# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] won't get HTTP_REFERER from facebook messenger app

Tags: php, facebook, http-referer

I have a script that get the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` when a user visits my page. This works great if it is used on facebook for desktop. But if a user click the link in the mobile app facebook messenger it can't get any `HTTP_REFERER`.

Anyone have a solution for getting info about if the user clicked a link in the facebook messenger app?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when a user clicks on a link the the facebook app, it isn't being redirected, but opened. Since the app isn't a web browser.

If you wanna track where people open your site from, you could parse in a UTM code (just a _GET parameter, but globally used to track origin, many sites like google also uses these, and some even auto append them.).

For more info, see the following article: http://www.launchdigitalmarketing.com/seo-definitions/what-are-utm-codes/